# AfterClose event present in jQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to handle afterClose event? How to do that?

When my Jquery datepicker popup completely close then I want to trigger blur event.

Want to know any other event provided by jquery datepicker after OnClose event fires

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look in docs... second to last option `onClose`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way by using the `onClose` of the date picker. This is called whenever the datepicker closes as per the description below.

> Called when the datepicker is closed, whether or not a date is selected. The function receives the selected date as text ("" if none) and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

**Sample Code:**

```
$( "someselector" ).datepicker({ 
    // some other options her
    onClose: myClose
});

function myClose(dateText, inst) {
     // code to blur HTML element or do whatever else you want here.
}
```

Comment: event which fires after onClose ?

Comment: @VaibhaV Why do you need something after onClose? What is it the onClose hinders?